# PostgreSQL: Why does DROP DATABASE databaseName keep Schemas and Relations of the deleted DB in psql?

Tags: database, postgresql, schema, psql, drop-database

In Postgres, PSQL one can execute commands from file with the `\i <path>` command.

I did this by creating a DATABASE, a SCHEMA, some TABLES, and a VIEW with this little file:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS databaseName;
CREATE DATABASE databaseName ;

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS databaseName_schema;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS databaseName_schema.tableName (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(80),
   surename VARCHAR(80),
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS databaseName_schema.tableMovies (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    priority SERIAL,
    movieName VARCHAR(40)
);
   
create or replace view versionViewTest as select version();
```

I then checked with \l and the database "databaseName" does exist.
If I then

```
DROP DATABASE databaseName;
```

and recheck \l the database is gone!
However when I then execute the same script again with

```
\i <path>
```

it says:

...schema already exists, skipping CREATE SCHEMA
...relation already exists, skipping CREATE TABLE

I already spent some time reading about schemas, relations, and Postgres and can not tell what I am missing.

My expectation would be: If I drop a database it's containing components also are dropped but somehow psql does not drop them but reuses them in case of the creation of a database with the exact same name in the future.
Why would that be useful?
And how would I drop the database with all its content?

PS: Any lecture on that topic is welcomed as well as a direct answer.

Comment: you miss connect to newly created database

Comment: `create database` copies `template1` maybe you have those schemas and tables in the template database?

Comment: I believe Simeon creates schema in database he is connected to, so drop/create database become irrelevant to next statements

Comment: @VaoTsun I was not actively connected to any database at the time I executed the script with the missing connect statement. Does your comment imply that I am always connected to a default Database in such a situation?

Comment: yes. if you would be connected to the db you drop, it would not allow you to. also psql starts "terminal" only after it connects to some db

Comment: It could not be that I was connected to the old db I dropped for it was gone and did no longer show up when listing \l all databases

Comment: no, you must have been connected to postgres or template(0)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot to connect to a db:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS databaseName;
CREATE DATABASE databaseName ;
\c databaseName 
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS databaseName_schema;
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept this as the correct answer as soon as the timer allows me to. 
Additional clarification: Would it be concidered "dirty" to name the script ".sql" after adding the psql-specific command '\c databaseName'?

Comment: it's common practice, and yet psql meta-commands are not SQL statements by all means. I believe it's a matter of choice.